# Analyzing collapsed data for statistical significance

Tags: statistical-significance, dataset

What is the proper way to analyze data that is only available in a collapsed format for statistical significance?

I am dealing with a dataset that contains at the observation level the arithmetic sum of some variables. For instance, one observations shows that 150 individuals were treated and that out of these 150 individuals 85 chose a certain action (the row vector hence looks like (150 85).
My goal is to analyze whether the treatment leads to significant difference in actions. I have multiple observations which, however, differ in the number of treated individuals.
An illustrative excerpt of the data looks like that: (Treatment "A" Individuals (n) 150 Actions (k) 85, Treatment "B" Individuals (n) 76 Actions (k) 34, Treatment "A" Individuals (n) 87 Actions (k) 50, Treatment "B" Individuals (n) 98 Actions (k) 85).

Running tests/regressions on this data feels weird. I tried to implement tests in STATA using frequency weights, which gets the number of individuals right. However, I am worried that the data is interpreted as if, e.g., out of the 150 observations, all 150 chose 85/150 as their response instead of that 85 chose 1 and (150-85) chose 0 (which is correct) - which would impair test statistic.

Comment: I can't figure out what you mean by '("A" 150 85,"B" 76 34, "A" 87 50,"B" 98 85).' What are A and B? Are these two separate expts to see if A and B are the same. // Best to give data in form Yes 85, No 65, Total 150. If you know how to make a $2 \times 2$ contingency table, that's the format to be used for tests. // The grand total in the lower-right corner should be the total number of subjects participating in the expt.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I edited the post as you suggested. Thank you also for the hint of the contigency table. Is there a possibility to allow covariats in contingency-like tests?

Comment: contingency table or logistic regression, with LR you can use covariables